# MYSQL - Having clause does not return any rows

Tags: mysql

Student Visa Approval Process

```
Table: STUDENT_MST

VISA_APPROVED:
    'P': Visa Approval is Pending
    'Y': Visa is Approved
    'N': Visa is not Approved

UNIVERSITY_APPROVED:
    'P': University Approval is Pending
    'Y': University has approved the Student
    'N': University has rejected the Student
```

| STUDENT_MST_ID | STUDENT_ID | STUDENT_FILE_ID | VISA_APPROVED | UNIVERSITY_APPROVED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'STU-1' | 'FILE-1' | 'P' | 'P' |
| 2 | 'STU-2' | 'FILE-2' | 'Y' | 'Y' |
| 3 | 'STU-3' | 'FILE-3' | 'N' | 'N' |
| 4 | 'STU-3' | 'FILE-4' | 'Y' | 'Y' |
| 5 | 'STU-4' | 'FILE-5' | 'N' | 'Y' |
| 6 | 'STU-4' | 'FILE-6' | 'Y' | 'Y' |
| 7 | 'STU-5' | 'FILE-7' | 'N' | 'Y' |
| 8 | 'STU-5' | 'FILE-8' | 'N' | 'Y' |
| 9 | 'STU-5' | 'FILE-9' | 'Y' | 'Y' |

```
Table: FILE_MST

FILE_PROCESSED:
    'N': File not processed
    'Y': File Processed
```

| FILE_MST_ID | STUDENT_FILE_ID | FILE_PROCESSED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'FILE-1' | 'N' |
| 2 | 'FILE-2' | 'Y' |
| 3 | 'FILE-3' | 'N' |
| 4 | 'FILE-4' | 'Y' |
| 5 | 'FILE-5' | 'Y' |
| 6 | 'FILE-6' | 'Y' |
| 7 | 'FILE-7' | 'Y' |
| 8 | 'FILE-8' | 'Y' |
| 9 | 'FILE-9' | 'Y' |

I want to fetch all the records where a student has applied more than once **[COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) > 1]** and only their Visa got first rejected and then approved **[studntMst.VISA_APPROVED in ('N','Y')]** and the file is processed **[fileMst.FILE_PROCESSED = 'Y']**

Following query is not returning any output.

```
SELECT 
studntMst.STUDENT_MST_ID,
studntMst.STUDENT_ID,
studntMst.VISA_APPROVED,
studntMst.UNIVERSITY_APPROVED,
fileMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID,
fileMst.FILE_PROCESSED
FROM 
STUDENT_MST studntMst
JOIN FILE_MST fileMst on fileMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID = studntMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID
and studntMst.VISA_APPROVED in ('N','Y')
and fileMst.FILE_PROCESSED = 'Y'
GROUP BY
studntMst.STUDENT_MST_ID,
studntMst.STUDENT_ID,
studntMst.VISA_APPROVED,
studntMst.UNIVERSITY_APPROVED,
fileMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID,
fileMst.FILE_PROCESSED
HAVING COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) > 1
ORDER BY studntMst.STUDENT_MST_ID desc;
```

Ideally it should return the following.

| STUDENT_MST_ID | STUDENT_ID | VISA_APPROVED | UNIVERSITY_APPROVED | STUDENT_FILE_ID | FILE_PROCESSED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | STU-5 | 'Y' | 'Y' | FILE-8 | 'Y' |
| 8 | STU-5 | 'N' | 'Y' | FILE-7 | 'Y' |
| 7 | STU-5 | 'N' | 'Y' | FILE-6 | 'Y' |
| 6 | STU-4 | 'Y' | 'Y' | FILE-5 | 'Y' |
| 5 | STU-4 | 'N' | 'Y' | FILE-4 | 'Y' |

[Queries](https://jsfiddle.net/bosj7r9d/) to create table and insert data.

Comment: If you include COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) in the select and run the code minus the having clause do you get any where > 1?

Comment: @P.Salmon added COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) in the select and replaced HAVING with WHERE COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) > 1 (added it before GROUP BY)... I am getting Error: misuse of aggregate: COUNT()

Comment: I have loaded your data and run your code and there are no instances where COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) > 1 https://dbfiddle.uk/kjJsCiS7

Comment: Your logic is flawed in that the group by is effectively distinct over all columns, figure out the 2 parts separately..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
STUDENT_MST studntMst
JOIN FILE_MST fileMst on fileMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID = studntMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID
and studntMst.STUDENT_ID in (
    SELECT 
    studntMst.STUDENT_ID
    FROM 
    STUDENT_MST studntMst
    JOIN FILE_MST fileMst on fileMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID = studntMst.STUDENT_FILE_ID
    and studntMst.VISA_APPROVED in ('N','Y')
    and fileMst.FILE_PROCESSED = 'Y'
    GROUP BY
    studntMst.STUDENT_ID
    HAVING COUNT(studntMst.STUDENT_ID) > 1
)
ORDER BY studntMst.STUDENT_MST_ID desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow up with three steps:

- join the "*STUDENT_MST*" table with the "*FILE_MST*" table on matching "*STUDENT_FILE_ID*" field and filtering out non-processed files (`f.FILE_PROCESSED <> 'Y'`)
- use two `SUM` window functions, one to identify the amount of rejected visas, another to identify the amount of approved visas
- filter out rows that have these window function values less than 1 (which means that the student has had their visa accepted and rejected at least once)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT s.*, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN VISA_APPROVED = 'Y' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID) AS y,
           SUM(CASE WHEN VISA_APPROVED = 'N' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID) AS n
    FROM       STUDENT_MST s
    INNER JOIN FILE_MST    f
            ON s.STUDENT_FILE_ID = f.STUDENT_FILE_ID
           AND f.FILE_PROCESSED = 'Y'
)
SELECT STUDENT_MST_ID,
       STUDENT_ID,
       STUDENT_FILE_ID,
       VISA_APPROVED,
       UNIVERSITY_APPROVED
FROM cte
WHERE y >= 1 AND n >= 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64XcXcP4u6xF7RtdDpfTfR/0).

Assumption: rejected visas come always before accepted visas. If this is not the case, you need an additional `LAST_VALUE` window function which gathers the last value for the visa state, partitioned by each student. Eventually filter out those students whose last visa state is not 'Y'.